# Calculus Residue 3

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I try to calculate

```
f[z_]:=1/(Cosh[Sqrt[3]\[Pi] z ]-Cos[z  \[Pi] ])
Assuming[k\[Element] Integers,Residue[f[z],{z,(2 I k)/(I+Sqrt[3])}]]
```

but the answer is 0 maybe need more options cause th pole is correct
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue can be computed by shifting, and then using [`TrigToExp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp) and [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify):

```
g[z_] := f[z + 2 I k/(I+Sqrt[3])]

res[k_] = Residue[FullSimplify[TrigToExp @ g[z], k\[Element]Integers], {z, 0}]
res[k] //TeXForm
```

> (2 E^((-1)^(1/3) Sqrt[3]
>      k π))/((I + Sqrt[3]) (-1 + (-1)^k E^(Sqrt[3] k π)) π)
>
> $\frac{2 e^{\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{3} \pi  k}}{\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) \pi  \left((-1)^k e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  k}-1\right)}$

Let's compare this formula to results obtained by using explicit values for `k`:

```
r1 = FullSimplify @ ComplexExpand @ Table[
    Residue[f[z], {z, 2 I k/(I + Sqrt[3])}],
    {k, 5}
];
r2 = FullSimplify @ Table[res[k], {k, 5}];

r1 === r2
```

> True

Comment: Thanks again Carl Woll

Answer (score 1):

The command works well for concrete values of $k$, e.g.

```
Residue[1/(Cosh[Sqrt[3] \[Pi] z] - 
Cos[z \[Pi]]), {z, (2 I*3)/(I + Sqrt[3])}]
```

> -(I/([Pi] (Sqrt[3] Sin[(6 Sqrt[3] [Pi])/(I + Sqrt[3])] + 
>       Sinh[(6 [Pi])/(I + Sqrt[3])])))

Comment: I already  knew it but I need for k  integers  thanks anyway